# Relation between $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module $\pi_n (X)$ and $\mathbb{Z}$-module $H_n (X)$ or $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module $H_n (\tilde{X})$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a finite CW-complex of $n$.

1. For $i\geq 2$, $\pi_i (X)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module.
2. for $i\geq 2$, $H_i (\tilde{X})$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module, where $\tilde{X}$ is the universal covering of $X$.

I know that  the connection between homotopy groups and homology groups is given by the Hurewicz-Theorem. But my question is that:

**My question**: Can we express $\pi_i (X)$ (as a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module) in terms of $H_i (X)$'s (as $\mathbb{Z}$-module) or $H_i (\tilde{X})$ (as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module) for $2\leq i\leq n$? (particularly when they are free).

Comment: What makes you believe that such a relation could exist?

Comment: @TheThinWhistler For example, you can take $X$ to be a finite wedge of $S^2$. Then $H_2 (X)$ is a free abelian group and $\pi_2 (X)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. Hence I think that there is a relation between them at least when they are free.

Comment: The homology groups of $S^2$ are all free while it has infinitely many non free homotopy groups.

Comment: @ChrisGerig I don't know this sequence. Could you explain me a little bit more about it please?

Comment: @FernandoMuro Yes, they are. but not as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(S^2)$-module. Am I right?

Comment: @M.Ramana you're not, $S^2$ is simply connected.

Comment: The collection of all the homotopy groups together with some data about the action of $\pi_1$ on them has been called a [Postnikov system](https://mathoverflow.net/q/159777), from which one can in principle reconstruct the full homotopy type, and the homology groups in particular. However, it seems that reconstruction result has not proven to be practically useful.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine that’s not the Pistnikov system. Also, there’s no way to recover a homotopy type from the homotopy groups equipped with the action of the fundamental groups. If that were true, simply connected spaces would be determined by their homotopy groups.

Comment: @FernandoMuro You're probably right that I gave an inaccurate summary of what a Postnikov system is supposed to be. I wouldn't be able to tell you the precise definition either. ^^) But in my understanding, in the references that I linked to, Postnikov did claim to have captured the complete homotopy type with algebraic data. If I'm wrong about that too, then I would happily be corrected.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine homotopy types can be captured by algebraic data, that's correct, in several ways actually, but homotopy groups don't suffice in any single way, not even when regarded as modules over the fundamental group. Postnikov systems are more complex.

Comment: Dear @FernandoMuro What about homotopy groups $\pi_i (X)$ for $(2\leq i\leq n)$ when $X=S^n$.  I think they are always free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. Am I correct?

Comment: @M.Ramana yes, you are, for obvious reasons. BTW your edited question does not improve too much because most examples you’ve been given are simply connected.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Sorry, you are right. I'll try to improve my question better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you're already aware of an exact sequence which implies Hurewicz's theorem, but if $X$ is a space with $\pi_i(X)=0$ for $1<i<n$ then we have
$$H_{n+1}(X)\to H_{n+1}(\pi)\to \pi_n(X)_{\pi}\to H_n(X)\stackrel{\psi}{\to} H_n(\pi)\to0$$ where $\pi=\pi_1(X)$ is the fundamental group and $H_*(\pi)$ is discrete group cohomology, and $\pi_n(X)_{\pi}$ denotes the coinvariants. See e.g. Ken Brown "Cohomology of Groups"  exercise VII.7.6.

Generally, without assumptions on the homotopy groups, that map $\psi$ exists (in all degrees) and is canonical: You take a projective resolution of $\mathbb Z$ over $\mathbb Z\pi$, and you take the complex of free $\mathbb Z\pi$-modules $C_*(\text{universal cover of }X)$, to build a canonical chain map between those resolutions that induces $\psi$. This is also explained in the above reference somewhere in Chapter II.

Comment: I didn't know that. That's a good point. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Chris Gerig: You are assuming $\pi _i(X)=0$ for $1<i<n$, right?